# Forcing a layout to be a certain height

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio

I am trying to make a layout simulating a Dialog.

I am inserting a ListFragment in my fragment container in this layout. I'm trying to accomplish two things:

1. Buttons always visible on the bottom of the layout
2. The layout does not take up the entire height of the screen.

But nothing I try seems to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_fragment_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/dialog_button_container"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/dialog_button_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button3"/>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

It always wants to take up the entire height of my screen no matter what I do.

Comment: You can set the buttons on the bottom by using: android:layout_alignParentBottom. This works only inside a relativelayout!

Comment: @OliverU. I am already doing all of that

Comment: The FrameLayout is the container for fragments

Comment: i would recommend to use PopupWindow like XxGoliathusxX mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

I dont exactly understand what you really want to do but I think the first thing to check out is [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). It pops up like a normal Dialog but you can completly customize its layout and of course the buttons too. You said you want to
"synthesize" it. Im sure it is not that hard to find the right dimens, fontsize and so on for the buttons. Mostly its all set to the default.

Comment: I had changed my question to ask something else instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want your activity's layout to be look like dialog you can use following lines in your manifest file:

```
<activity
        android:name="Your activity name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog" />
```